# Measures to mitigate openmp parallel latency

Tags: c++, performance, fortran, mpi, openmp

I've written this question from a Fortran perspective, but the questions are not limited to Fortran alone (hence the c++ tag).

I have two questions. I've read that latency exists at the start and stop of OpenMP parallel loops [here](http://www.openmp.org/presentations/miguel/F95_OpenMPv1_v2.pdf). My questions are:

Q1) What practical measures are there to mitigate openMP latency?

Q2) Which of the following methods will perform better?

**method 1**

```
 x = 1.0; y = 2.0
 !$OMP PARALLEL DO
 do k=1,Nz; do j=1,Ny; do i=1,Nx
 x(i,j,k) = x(i,j,k)+y(i,j,k)
 enddo; enddo; enddo
 !$OMP END PARALLEL DO

 !$OMP PARALLEL DO
 do k=1,Nz; do j=1,Ny; do i=1,Nx
 x(i,j,k) = x(i,j,k)*y(i,j,k)
 enddo; enddo; enddo
 !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
 ! (x should = 6.0 at this point)
```

**method 2**

```
 x = 1.0; y = 2.0
 !$OMP PARALLEL DO
 do k=1,Nz; do j=1,Ny; do i=1,Nx
 x(i,j,k) = x(i,j,k)+y(i,j,k)
 x(i,j,k) = x(i,j,k)*y(i,j,k)
 enddo; enddo; enddo
 !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
 ! (x should = 6.0 at this point)
```

**method 3**

1) Create an object containing an array of procedures

2) Call the array of procedures as follows

```
 x = 1.0; y = 2.0
 !$OMP PARALLEL DO
 do k=1,Nz; do j=1,Ny; do i=1,Nx
 do t=1,procedure_array%N
 call procedure_array%single_procedure(t)%P(x(i,j,k),y(i,j,k))
 enddo
 enddo; enddo; enddo
 !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
 ! (x should = 6.0 at this point)
```

Let's suppose that `procedure_array%N = 2` and

```
 procedure_array%single_procedure(1)
 procedure_array%single_procedure(2)
```

Point to subroutines `add` (`x=x+y`) and `multiply` (`x=x*y`) respectively.

3) cleanup (deallocate)

**Comments**

First, it's clear that method 2 is superior to method 1, so I'm really interested in the comparison of method 2 to method 3. Second, I know that "try it out and see" is a valid answer, but I want to know if there are concrete examples of method 3 being used in practice (or industry) or conceptual reasons why method 3 is inferior compared to method 2 (e.g. overhead due to many procedure calls). Finally, if there is some sort of special care that can be taken (e.g., by specifically specifying particular threads) to make methods 2 and 3 virtually equivalent, what are they?

I appreciate any help!

**Updates**

In light of the comments, I've made the following corrections.

- modified the operations (thank you, @Gilles)
- removed everything related to MPI, this is really an openmp question (thank you, @Vladimir)
- Added clarification below (my own realizing)

And thank you, @innoSPG, about your answer about cache memory (and cache fault), that was very informative and helpful!

**Clarification**

Finally, from the comments, I've realized that the focus of this question is actually about the procedure call and not strictly related to openmp parallelization. That said, I've left the openmp statements because that is what is going on in my more complicated application, which I would like to preserve as much as possible. It seems like, from @Chaosit's comment that the procedure call will require overhead, slowing method 3. Is there any way to get around this?

Also, please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the two operations in method 2 will be executed in the written order, resulting in the correct final `x` value.

Comment: Putting aside that both computations in the snippets make no sense (OK, it's just to show we do some computation), it turns out that **method 1** and **method 2** aren't equivalent, because order matters (a lot in this case). So your assertion that "method 2 is superior to method 1" is highly questionable since **method 2** is wrong if the reference is the result obtained from **method 1** (unless `a=b=0`). I know, this isn't your point, but I'm all for correctness before efficiency.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a *"MPI parallelization loops"*? There is no such a thing.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that the difference you are looking for (method 2 and method 3) does not depend on the parallelization.

Let me explain:

Method 3 will possibly have another overhead due to procedure call that is not present in method 2. I am saying possibly because I am not familiar with procedure pointers, however, my guess is that the optimization by the compiler will not inline the procedure call if you are using procedure pointers.

That overhead due to procedure call is absolutely independent of the parallelization. You will still have it in the sequential code. It is not part of the parallelization latency.

Now, I am taking the risk to go back to the option that you do not like: try and see. I am taking this risk because I believe that what you showed is only an illustration of your problem and that your actual case is more complex. When you get into complex cases, you might be surprised that the conclusion between method 1 and 2 is not valid anymore. It can be strongly dependent on the problem you have in hand. The conclusion for one case will not hold for another one. As intelligent as compilers are nowadays, they will not catch everything. In computer science, there is this notion of cache memory that is sometime not well understood, but I will not go into details. You can have a case where each single loop (data and/or code) of method 1 hold in the cache memory while the combine loop of case 2 does not hold in the cache memory. The simplistic illustration is the case where method 2 experience a cache fault inside the inner loop while method 1 does not. In that case, you will see that method 1 is highly superior to method 2 for large loop bounds.

That is where the `Try and see` becomes the standard, and that is what happens most of the time for real life cases.

Comment: You're right regarding the third method - most likely it is going to be slower compared to the first two due to the fact that procedure pointers are resolved at the runtime and not at the compile time. Therefore, compiler cannot do anything to optimize this part of the code - it has to use it as it is. As for the comparison between first two methods - this will highly depend on the compiler - but with modern compilers I would expect that both can perform equally fast